# Sort lines by date

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, datetime

So I have a .txt file that contains some lines...
Each line has the following format: `x (A-Z) creationDate completionDate Task +project @context` (TODO list project)

So I want to sort those lines by their creationDate (and completionDate for the second case) and write them in a .txt file.

Example:

```
  (D) 2018-03-02 2018-04-04 watch the new tomb raider +movie @tombraider
  (A) 2017-03-02 2017-03-10 say goodbye to your best friend!! +friendship @meetfriend

x (C) 2016-07-02 2016-08-05 finish gta vice city +gaming @playstation2
```

after sort:

```
x (C) 2016-07-02 2016-08-05 finish gta vice city +gaming @playstation2
  (A) 2017-03-02 2017-03-10 say goodbye to your best friend!! +friendship @meetfriend
  (D) 2018-03-02 2018-04-04 watch the new tomb raider +movie @tombraider
```

How can I do this?

Thank you for taking time to answer.

Comment: So does every line have "x" at the beginning? Or just (C)?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: If a line starts with an  'x' so is it, else it starts with a space.

Comment: Use a regular expression to extract the date then, pass that to `datetime.strptime()` and sort on the result. There are several posts on this site alone that can help you with those steps.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sorted()` and `lambda`

```
with open(myfile, 'r') as f:
    lines = [line.strip().split() for line in f]

sorted_lines = sorted(lines, key = lambda x: x[2])
```

This assumes that ever line will have the `creationDate` at position 2. However, as a comment already pointed out, do some lines have an `x` prefix and some dont? If they don't, is there a character there (e.g. `\s` or `\t`)?

Comment: Yes, they either start with an 'x' or space '\s'